# Juju Bare Metal 14.04 behind proxy ignoring proxy settings

Tags: networking, server, juju, proxy, maas

I have installed `Juju` on my MAAS server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and provided the following `environment.yaml` (debug output attached):

http://pastebin.com/a02LnNbw

When I run `juju` anything (bootstrap, tools-sync) it goes straight to the internet instead of using the proxy:

```
root@clustermaster01:~/.juju# netstat -untap | grep :443
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.x:36706     91.189.88.141:443       SYN_SENT    31816/juju
```

I have `wget`, `apt`, and my `env` set to use the same outbound internet proxy and get pull updates using `apt-get` all day.  I also have the MAAS `Squid-deb-proxy` set up as a child of this internet gateway proxy and successfully bridging MAAS software in.

How do I get `Juju` to honor either the local squid or outbound proxy?

Comment: Posted a bug report;  https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1383389

Comment: The root cause is apparently not a bug, but a problem with our local network security policies outside of Ubuntu configurations, and not begin able to determine what on the internet needs to be connected to for the installation to work to get the destinations whitelisted. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `juju bootstrap --upload-tools` as a workaround. It should avoid the need for Juju to go out to the internet for getting the tools.

Comment: The issue is with deriving every source and destination to complete the installation process to have the traffic allowed on my network and have the destinations classified properly on the outbound internet proxies.  I will check the docs, but am guessing I may have to rip through the source to find them all.

Comment: The problem apperas to be with the juju host that is being bootstrapped not honoring the no_proxy settings in environments.yaml, and the process not allowing me to set them on the host that is being provisioned.